# Remote Validation with Attribute Validation in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am using ASP.NET CORE RC1 and I have the following model:

```
public class AccountSignUpModel {

  [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Email is invalid")]
  [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email is required")]
  [Remote("IsEmailAvailable", "Validation", ErrorMessage = "Email already used", HttpMethod = "Get")]
  public String Email { get; set; }

}
```

And I have the following controller:

```
public class ValidationController : Controller {
  [HttpGet]
  public IActionResult IsEmailAvailable(String email) {
    return Json(false);
  }
}
```

When I submit the form with an email it becomes always valid.

I placed an breakpoint inside IsEmailAvailable action and it does not fire.

Any idea why this happens?

Comment: Have you tried making the return type `bool` and just returning `true` or `false` - or having the return type as `JsonResult`)?

Comment: Have you tried it with the exact case `String Email` instead of `String email`?

Comment: @Dumisani I just tried with Email but it does not solve the problem.

Comment: @stephen.vakil Yes, I tried with JsonResult and using String Email as argument and the validation does no fire.

Comment: When you debug using your browser developer tools, does it seem to be attempting the ajax call?  Is it possible that you need to decorate with AllowAnonymous or anything to ensure the call succeeds?

Comment: @stephen.vakil I don't see any error ... And I added Allow Anonymous and still does not fire. That is the problem ... I don't get any error and the action does not fire.

Comment: Side note: Since the method is `[HttpGet]`, it needs to be `return Json(false, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`. What is the actual html generated for that property?

Answer (score 0):

You have marked the action with the [HttpGet] verb rather than the [HttpPost] verb. Also the parameter of your action should be of type AccountSignUpModel not String otherwise the validation rules won't work.

Comment: I tried your suggestions and changed the verb to HttpPost and added the AccountSignUpModel as parameter of the action method but it didn't work. The model is always valid and the breakpoint does not even fire. I have no idea what is going on ...